# How to query FieldDefinition records?

Tags: soap-api, query, standard-objects, spring15

When trying to query [FieldDefinition](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_tooling/Content/sforce_api_objects_fielddefinition.htm)s through SOAP API, I get the following error:

```
[UnexpectedErrorFault [ApiFault  exceptionCode='EXTERNAL_OBJECT_UNSUPPORTED_EXCEPTION'
 exceptionMessage='FieldDefinition: a filter on a reified column is required.'
]
]
```

I couldn't find anything about querying `FieldDefinition`s in the official SF docs.

Does anyone know what's a reified column for Salesforce and how to query `FieldDefinition`s?

Thanks a lot!

Haris

Comment: what do you mean by the FieldDefinition? Do you mean the Fields on the SObjects? can you please share your request xml?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Rajiv. `FieldDefinition` is a standard object. I'm using Java to make requests.

Comment: sorry for my ignorance but I am not aware of any such standard object. Which Salesforce application (sales, service or marketing cloud) are you connecting?

Comment: Here's a link to the object: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_tooling/Content/sforce_api_objects_fielddefinition.htm . I'm accessing users data through SOAP API?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message is not very user friendly but what it hints is to provide at least one filter while querying FieldDefinition.

For example you can filter the query by using [EntityDefinition](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_tooling/index_Left.htm)

**Example**

```
select id,DataType,NamespacePrefix,DeveloperName 
from FieldDefinition 
where EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName = 'Account'
```

When we remove the where clause from the query we would see the same error that you have reported.

The [Tooling API developer's guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_toolingpre/api_tooling.pdf) for Summer'15 is updated with some query examples.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot. One question on the fly: What's the difference between `FieldDefinition` and `Field`?

Comment: I am sorry but Field in context of tooling api or some other context? coz i dont see anything like Field available in the tooling api.

Comment: In the context of SOAP API, since there's Field and FieldDefinition in the SOAP API.

Comment: If you want to pull multiple object names, use: select EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName id,DataType,NamespacePrefix,DeveloperName 
from FieldDefinition 
where EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName in ( 'Account','Contact')