# What is a reified column and how to get all value from it?

Tags: soql, externalid

There are some objects (like FieldDefinition or AppTabMember) that when you want to uses SOSL SELECT all data from them, it fails with "a filter on a reified column is required". I have a lot of questions about these objects, especially:

- Is there a way to extract all the values from these kind of objects?
- Can a custom object be created with reified columns? (Are those columns declared as external reference IDs or something else?)

Comment: similar question [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/73572/how-to-query-fielddefinition-records). I don't think you can create reified fields in custom objects.

Comment: I have seen multiple answers like that but none of them answered the 2 questions above: "can you extract all the values?" and "Can you create a custom object that behaves with such reified columns?"